# Set form value to Magento Session

Tags: jquery, core-session, magento-1.9.3.6, unserialize

I am using Magento 1.9.3.6 version.

I need form values in the controller which is other than form action. So I serialized the form values and set into the Magento Core session like below. When I print the Session Value it is returns empty or the variable name as value.

```
var samples = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#sell-add-product').serializeArray());
var a = "<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyValue("+samples+");?>";
```

I am getting like below in the controller:

```
 $data = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyValue();
 print_r($data);
```

Out put is `+samples+`

Comment: We cannot assign Javascript variable value to php. You need to set session where form posted. Means you need to assign/set form values in post action.

Comment: you can do this things using Ajax request.